# Download CSV from serverside to browser in Laravel 4

Tags: php, csv, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4 framework, I have a function that creates a csv file called data_78888.csv the number 78888 changes everytime the function is run to generate a csv file. That function returns a string like that : "Download/78888"

The folder where my csv files are created is  called "outputs" and is located in my project folder where the app folder is located to, (it is not in the public folder).

What I would like to do is to create a route that points to my Process controller like that :

```
Route::get('Download/{token}', array('uses' => 'ProcessController@downloadCSV'));
```

In my controller I would like to send that csv file to the browser to download it , I'm doing like that :

```
<?php

class ProcessController extends BaseController {

 public function downloadCSV($token){
        $fileToDownload = "data_".$token.".csv";
        $filePath = "outputs/";
        return Response::download($filePath, $fileToDownload, array(
            'Content-Type'              => 'text/csv',
            'Content-Disposition'       => 'attachment;filename="'.$fileToDownload

        ));
    }
}
```

The issue is that this is not working and I get an html file called 78888.htm and an error on the server.

How can I make this working please?

Answer (score 0):

The path to the file has to include the name and file extension of the file.

So try this;

```
$fileToDownload = "data_".$token.".csv";
$filePath = base_path() . "outputs/" . $fileToDownload;
return Response::download($filePath, $fileToDownload, array(
    'Content-Type'              => 'text/csv',
    'Content-Disposition'       => 'attachment;filename="'.$fileToDownload

));
```

Also make sure the file exists, before downloading.

Comment: Sorry this did not fix the issue, I still get the same error

Comment: What is within the htm file that you get? Did you get any errors within the logs?

Comment: there is so many errors in the log I can't post them all but the html file is never downloaded it says error with the server

Comment: Look through the errors then. We cannot find out the errors for you without some sort of help. Try clearing the log file then doing the request again. The log file should then have the error that occured.

Comment: I had a look at the log, there is two erors I could fix one witch is :I needed to add / in : $filePath = base_path() . "outputs/" . $fileToDownload; to make it $filePath = base_path() . "/outputs/" . $fileToDownload; the second error is that in my csv function I'm using : $f = fopen('php://temp', 'w'); that php://temp is the source of the error how can I open a file in temporary folder in Laravel please?

Comment: Can you verify that the .csv file is getting created successfully in `outputs`? Sharing your code for the function that generates and saves the .csv file would help.